# Add files to watch-list in karma preprocessor

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, karma-runner, rollupjs

> ### Here is a repository created to demonstrate the issue:
>
> #### [brianmhunt/karma-rollup-preprocessor-issue-3](https://github.com/brianmhunt/karma-rollup-preprocessor-issue-3)

I'm trying to get karma-rollup-preprocessor working with Karma's builtin watch i.e. solve [showpad/karma-rollup-preprocessor#3](https://github.com/showpad/karma-rollup-preprocessor/issues/3)

In other words, in a preprocessor, I want to add files to Karma's watch list.

It's easy to get the list of files Rollup uses to compile. Rollup returns a list of files that it reads (ones one wants to watch), so in the preprocessor I am trying to add files to the list karma watches.

Basically I want to add this (or the working equivalent) to the preprocessor:

```
bundle.modules.forEach((module) => {
    files.unshift({
        pattern: module.id,  /* The full file path, from Rollup */
        watched: true,
        included: false,
        nocache: false,
        served: false,
    })
})
```

Where `files` is Karma's `config.files` or `fileList` or whatever place one needs to put the files being watched.

Doing the above with `config.files`, the files are indeed being added to the watcher, but [`.on(fileList.changeFile)`](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/blob/master/lib/watcher.js#L101) fails the [`_isIncluded`](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/blob/master/lib/file-list.js#L104).

So it looks like the files also (or alternatively) must be added to the `fileList`.

Unfortunately when I try to add the `fileList` to the [`$inject`](https://github.com/showpad/karma-rollup-preprocessor/blob/master/lib/index.js#L58), I get the error:

> Error: Can not resolve circular dependency! (Resolving: preprocess -> preprocessor:rollup -> fileList -> preprocess).

I've looked at basically all the other preprocessors that look like they could also add includes, but I have found no indication of how to do it.

Is there a canonical way to add files Karma should watch from a preprocessor?  Or otherwise how might one do this?  This seems pretty clutch for a preprocessor in Karma, so it's surprising that it's not documented, apparent, or problematic in the other preprocessors.

**EDIT**  Here's some more attempts:

I tried to add the watched patterns to the `config.files` in `karma.conf` i.e.

```
files: [
   "spec/**/*.js",
   {pattern:"src/**/*.js", included: false, watched: true}
]
```

But the `src/*` doesn't recompile when changed.  The tests just re-run.

So I tried chokidar like this:

```
var server = new karma.Server(options)...

chokidar.watch("src/**/*.js")
  .on('add', server.refreshFiles.bind(server))
  .on('change', server.refreshFiles.bind(server))
```

I also tried it with a debounce, in case Karma was slower on the refresh, but it seems the tests won't re-run.

I rooted around karma-browserify for inspiration but it was a bit too convoluted to pick up without delving in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've [issued a pull request to resolve this](https://github.com/showpad/karma-rollup-preprocessor/pull/11).

Until it is merged one can use my repo  i.e. put `"karma-rollup-preprocessor": "brianmhunt/karma-rollup-preprocessor"` in `package.json` dependencies or devDependencies.

EDIT:  Superceded by https://github.com/Kflash/karma-rollup-plugin